# Get reference from button in HTML to use in a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm working on a project using the Firebase and Firestore Databases (I'm brand new to this ). I watched [this firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU). In that firecast he uploaded the file to storage once the 'choose file' button was pressed in the browser.

```
    var uploader = document.getElementById(fileButton); //Create ref to button
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function (e){ 
       //Get file
       var file=e.target.files[0];
       //Create a storage ref
       var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('sweet_gifs/'+file.name);
       //Upload file
       var task = storageRef.put(file);
    })
```

In the snippet above the file is uploaded once the 'choose file' button on the HTML form, which is linked to the fileButton variable, changes state.However I want to upload it once I press the submit button on a form, not the 'choose file' button. The main issue I'm struggling to understand is how to link the file that was selected by the 'choose file' button and use it in the "submit" event listener from another button. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: You need to provide examples. Questions should be self-contained. Don't expect people to go watch a video first.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane thank you, I've edited the question to include the relevant information from the firecast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get an element.

- [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is traditional
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is modern and flexible
- [`getElementByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) are options
- The [`elements` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) of a form is available

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question to make what I'm asking a bit clearer

Comment: @S.Ramjit — It doesn't make it any clearer. You're getting the file input when the change event fires on it. This answer tells you how to get the file input when the submit button is clicked. What's left to say?

Comment: Apologies I'm still learning. When the change event fires the line var file=e.target.files[0]; creates a reference to the file that was selected but can I still use that reference in another event listener or is it destroyed once the change event listener function finishes executing?

Comment: @S.Ramjit — Why are you trying to preserve it across multiple events instead of just reading the file from the file input directly when the submit event fires?

Comment: Because I'd like to start the file upload once the user is finished with the form i.e. by clicking on a submit button and not when the user selects the file for upload. Can I grab a reference to the file by saying var file=document.getElementById('fileButton').files[0]?